# Fazer o Rebase de DLL ou EXE, vale a pena?

Tags: framework, dll, gerenciamento-de-memória

Durante o desenvolvimento de um *assembly*, acabei "descobrindo" a seguinte opção:

> Project Properties > Build > Advanced > **[DLL Base Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh7adf4f.aspx)**

e buscando informações a respeito, entendi que poderemos especificar o endereço de base para carregar a DLL (ou EXE) (reduzindo a paginação e melhorando o desempenho) mas, não entendi exatamente o que é isso e fiquei com as dúvidas:

1. O que significa alterar este valor base?
2. Como ocorre a paginação de DLLs ou EXEs?
3. O que ganho em performance?
4. Como posso mensurar o tamanho para atribuir um valor correto?